# Ansible Restarting VMware vCenter Server Appliance

Tags: ansible, vmware, vcenter

I would like to simply reboot the VCSA using Ansible as part of a development workflow. Does anybody have any ideas as to how to do so?

https://kb.vmware.com/s/article/2147152

This would normally be done by hitting 'shell' and then turning off/on the service and/or 'reboot'

I've been playing around with ansible.raw, but it seems to hang indefinitely.

A few of the attempts I have tried:

tasks:

```
- name: 'get into the shell'
  raw: 'shell'
  register: shell
- debug: msg="{{ shell }}"

- name: 'reboot'
  raw: 'reboot'
  register: reboot
- debug: msg="{{ reboot }}"

- name: Unconditionally reboot the machine with all defaults
  reboot:
```

Comment: Hi Kevin
It would be useful to see what your current task look like

Comment: How about guest reboot with [vmware_guest module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/community/vmware/vmware_guest_module.html)?

Comment: I have added a few of the tasks I have tried @M_DK. In addition, that module is intended to reboot the VMs in vCenter rather than the vCenter VCSA itself. It's a bit of weird operation so I'm not surprised its not well documented.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this by manually going into every system and changing the default shell to /bin/bash

https://communities.vmware.com/t5/vCenter-Server-Discussions/Access-to-VCSA-through-SSH-and-or-local-console-is-NOT-working/td-p/1816293

############

~# vi /etc/passwd

and change the appliancesh to /bin/bash

root:x:0:0:root:/root:/bin/bash

Also make sure that ssh access for root is enabled from /etc/ssh/sshd_config